# "This value is not valid" when using "query_builder" on "entity" buildForm on symfony2.1

Tags: symfony, entity, query-builder

Here is my problem.
I use the `buildForm` method on symfony 2.1 in order to build my form.
With the following code everything works just fine :

```
$builder->add('combat','entity',array(
                    class' => 'KarateCompetitionBundle:CompetitionCombat',
                    'empty_value' => 'Sélectionner un combat'));
```

But I want to filter and display only some `Combat`. That's why I have to use the `query_builder` option. When i do that i get the `This value is not valid` error message.
Here is the code :

```
$builder->add('combat','entity',array(
                  'class' => 'KarateCompetitionBundle:CompetitionCombat',
                  'empty_value' => 'Sélectionner un combat',
                  'query_builder' => function(CombatRepository $cr) {
                      return $cr->getAllWithoutBilanQueryBuilder();}));
```

I reduce at the minimum the code (i.e. no filtering on the `getAllWithoutBilanQueryBuilder`method) in order to be able to find the problem.

```
public function getAllWithoutBilanQueryBuilder(){
    $queryBuilder = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
    return $queryBuilder->select('c')->from('KarateEntrainementBundle:CompetitionCombat', 'c');
```

}

I've compared both html code generate on each case and they are the same.

I put a `var_dump($object)` on the controller after binding the form with the request `$form->bind($request)` and it appears that when i use the `query_builder` option the `combat`is null while it is not null if i don't use it.

I can't manage to understand why ? 
I found few post on the web with the same issue but none with an answer.
Is it possible that there is a symfony issue here or am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: It's probably just a copy/paste thing but you do have two different method names:  getAllWithoutScoreQueryBuilder and getAllWithoutBilanQueryBuilder.  $this->ENTITY seems a bit suspicious.  Does it work if you just return the created queryBuilder form your method?  Make a command object or unittest and verify that a valid query builder is being returned with CompetitionCombat objects as the result.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it was a copy/past thing. I edit my question to correct that. `$this->Entity` is a global variable in order not to repeat each time. I edit my question and replace it for better understanding. Actually, I know the `querybuilder` is correct because my form is well generated. I have the list of combats. But when i select one, and validate the form then I have the error message. What is weird is that if i put the `query_builder` property or if I don't, both html codes are the same. But without the `query_builder` property I can select a combat and validate and there is no error.

Comment: You only have one entity manager and it is named default?

Comment: I don't understand the question. I guess, yes, I only have one entity manager. I get it via `$this->getEntityManager` from a custom repository that extends `EntityRepository`

Comment: It's possible to have multiple entity managers, each with a different name in which case you need to set the em parameter.  But clearly you are not doing that.

Comment: Are you doing any special validation?  Do you have a validation.yml file?  Just kind of shooting in the dark here.

Comment: I do not have a validation file. But I have some validation on `Combat` entity :  `UniqueConstraint(columns={"idCompetition", "idCategorie","tour"})})`on the table ; `@UniqueEntity(fields={"competition","categorie","tour"},message="my error message")` and `@Assert\Callback(methods={"isValid"})` on the class. With `public function isValid(ExecutionContext $context){if ($this->finale && $this->demiFinale){$context->addViolation('message erreur', array(), null);}}`

Comment: But i do not think these validations are relevant on that problem.

Comment: And thank you. I didn't know abut the possibility of having many entity managers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to make this worked :-)

So here was the fix.
On the `getAllWithoutBilanQueryBuilder` function, I replace

```
$queryBuilder = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
```

by

```
$queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('c');
```

I don't know what is exactly the difference and why this is now working.
But this is working.

Thanks you all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem and - in my case - traced it back to Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\ChoiceList\ORMQueryBuilderLoader.

When the form is validated, the entities are loaded by primary key in ORMQueryBuilderLoader::getEntitiesByIds() by adding an IN() clause to the query builder. In my case, this IN() clause was ineffective and all selectable entities were returned.

This, in turn, caused Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\DataTransformer\ChoicesToValuesTransformer::reverseTransform() to throw a TransformationFailedException, because the number of loaded entities and submitted choices were not the same.

I suppose there's other possible causes for this specific error. Here's what you could try:

- Look at the generated query, run it manually and make sure it returns *only* the selected values
- In Symfony\Component\Form\Form, try outputting the caught TransformationFailedException and see where it leads you.
- If none of the above seem plausible, add some debug output to Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Validator\Constraints\FormValidator and see whether you can narrow it down somewhat.

Comment: Thanks for your help ! So I've try what you said. I've executed the query manually and everything is ok. Then i output the TransofrmationFailedException. Here is the error message : The choice "16" does not exist or is not unique. "16" is the id of the selected combat. And as a matter of fact, I check the DB and there is a combat with the id "16" and there is only one. So I didn't understand why I get this error. Thank you for your help. At least now, i know a little more. :-)

Comment: @Mike I 'm running into the exact same issue too, with the same symptoms, ie: at validation, a 'IN' is added to the DB query making the validation failing as the submitted value isn't anymore in the possible values :(... How can we get rid of this 'IN' that get added automatically ?

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to @mike-b answer: for me failing QueryBuilder statement was ->having('...') query part:

```
    ...
    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use ($pn) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('p')
                                    ->select('p')
                                    ->join('p.product', 'pr')
                                    ->where('p.name = ' . $pn->getId())
                                    ->andWhere("LENGTH(p.value_en) > 1")
                                    ->andWhere("p.value_en != ''")
                                    /* when I remove this - validation passe flawlessly  */
                                    ->having('COUNT(pr.id) > 1')
                                    ->groupBy('p.value_en)
                                    ->orderBy('p.value_en', 'ASC');
    ...
```

tested with Symfony version 2.3.6