# Adding 'choice' option to 'entity' type form field invalidates form -- Symfony2

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I've run into this issue which I can't resolve.

On one of my forms, there is a requirement to filter the entities.

A bit of background:

The form is to add a new task to a workflow step. The tasks that can be selected depend on what stage in the workflow the user is at, what product is assigned to the workflow and the company that manages that workflow.

I tried adding in the filtering query into the 'query_builder' section, and I have tried to put the query result from the entity repository into the 'choices' section in the array.

However, the form always comes back saying that the field I'm working on is invalid. The most puzzling part is, without the 'choices' field, as in, when it's bringing in ALL the records for that entity, the select box is exactly the same (with a few extra records) - the name, and pattern of how it's written. And that works fine. So I have absolutely no idea of what's going on.

The form element code:

```
->add('instructionAction', 'entity', array(
            'label' => 'Action',
            'empty_value' => 'Select Action',
            'required' => true,
            'class' => 'ApplicationTrackpadCommonBundle:InstructionAction',
            'property' => 'description',
            'choices' => $this->instructionActionRepository->findAllForCaseInstruction( $options['caseInstructionId'] )
            )
)
```

I'm not sure how much code I can post as it is for client work. The query I use is properly populating the dropdown box like it would without the query, and even if I select all of the entity without any `WHERE` clauses, the same problem occurs.

Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: You say that if you remove the "choices" option everyhting is working? (of course it will show all entities) is the data you are passing to the form valid? i mean available in the restricted list?

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
->add('instructionAction', 'entity', array(
    'required' => true,
    'class' => 'ApplicationTrackpadCommonBundle:InstructionAction',
    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use ($user) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
            ->where('c.user = :user')
            ->setParameter('user', $user)
            ->orderBy('c.name', 'ASC');
 }))
```

You can pass variables using the `use`.

Comment: Like I said in the original post, I get the same error with the query builder. The thing is, with a basic QB (no multiple `FROM` or `WHERE`'s it does work, but when I add in the other entities to filter the result set it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use the "query_builder" instead of "choices" option ? I think that the "choices" option is directly overridden by the the "query_builder" when you use a entity type. Like described in the symfony documentation  [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html).
If it still doesn't work, I suggest you should take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15192735/this-value-is-not-valid-when-using-query-builder-on-entity-buildform-on-sy).

Comment: Like I said in the original post, I get the same error with the query builder. The thing is, with a basic QB (no multiple FROM or WHERE's it does work, but when I add in the other entities to filter the result set it doesn't work.